# Full text search in concrete node in json

Tags: json, postgresql

I  has table "**Product**" with two columns:

1. Id - **Bigint** primary key
2. data - **Jsonb**

Here example of json:

```
{
  "availability": [
    {
      "qty": 10,
      "price": 42511,
      "store": {
        "name": "my_best_store",
        "hours": null,
        "title": {
          "en": null
        },
        "coords": null,
        "address": null,
```

I insert json to column "**data**".

Here sql get find  "**my_best_store**"

```
select *
from product
where to_tsvector(product.data) @@ to_tsquery('my_best_store')
```

Nice. It's work fine.

But I  need to find "**my_best_store**" only in section "**availability**".

I try this but result is empty:

```
select *
from product
where to_tsvector(product.data) @@ to_tsquery('availability & my_best_store')
```

Comment: `to_tsvector(product.data -> 'availability') @@ ...`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But I also need to find in section "availability.store". And this not help: to_tsvector(product.data -> 'availability' -> 'store') @@

Comment: Do you only want to search in the first array element or all array elements in `availability`? Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In the all array elements. Postgres ver 9.6

Comment: My suggestion would work with [newer versions](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=031e3e4da62d613651cd2178a58c652d) are you able to upgrade?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name After upgrade how I can find solution of my task? Some new methods in Postgres?

Comment: `to_tsvector(product.data -> 'availability') @@ to_tsquery('my_best_store')` [as shown](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=031e3e4da62d613651cd2178a58c652d) in my previous comment

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OK, this work. But I need also to find not only in "availability" , but also in section "availability.store.name" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to search in the name attribute, you can do the following:

```
select p.*
from product p
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(p.data -> 'availability') as t(item)
              where to_tsvector(t.item -> 'store' ->> 'name') @@ to_tsquery('my_best_store'))
```

With Postgres 12, you can simplify that to:

```
select p.*
from product p
where to_tsvector(jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$.availability[*].store.name')) @@ to_tsquery('my_best_store')
```